# Termux processes killed on Android 13 even with phantom procs off

Tags: termux, background-process, android-13

On Android 11, I am able to run `text-generation-ui` under Termux, with 3b models. I've got a Samsung A53 phone, with 6GB RAM & 2GB swap (by default).

However, on Android 13, I'm currently running LineageOS 20 GSI (Android 13), installed over stock Android 12. (with some custom kernel from Andi Yan), the OS is killing Termux processes. When I start `server.py`, it goes just "killed" with no messages at all.

In the developer options, I've turned off the feature flags `monitor_phantom_procs`. I also ran these commands in adb:

1. `adb shell /system/bin/device_config set_sync_disabled_for_tests persistent`
2. `/system/bin/device_config put activity_manager max_phantom_processes 2147483647`

What can I do to stop the OS from killing procs?